# Can Chosen.js search the values of options as well as their text?

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, drop-down-menu, jquery-select2, jquery-chosen

I am using the jQuery plugin Chosen.js with a long list of options. Sometimes people search for abbreviations that occur in the `value` attribute but not in the human-readable text displayed for an `option`. Is there a way to instruct Chosen.js to search values as well as option texts?

For instance, given this option in a select box ...

```
<option value="TX">Texas</option>
```

... I want Chosen.js to show this option even if a user just types “tx” and nothing else.
By default, neither Chosen.js nor Select2 show a result in this case.

Comment: I couldn't find anything in the documentation.  I know this is possible using Igor Vaynberg's Select2, which I believe is based on or derived from Chosen.

Comment: I went through the documentation of Select2 twice but could not locate the desired feature. Maybe it's the JavaScript jargon I do not always understand.

Comment: I believe what you are looking for is this:  ivaynberg.github.io/select2/#matcher. Let me know if I'm wrong.

Comment: Indeed this should work. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Select2 matcher from [ivaynberg.github.io/select2/#matcher](http://ivaynberg.github.io/select2/#matcher) supports matching value from both the option text and the associated value.

The solution is already mentioned in the comments, adding this answer to remove this question from unanswered queue.